# Login panel .feature (gherkin) file

Tags: algorithm, bdd, cucumber

I think many days ago, I randomly got introduced to [**cucumber developement**](https://cucumber.io/), And it seemed like a conventional and interesting principle of software development.

At this very time, I'm concentrating on creating a Linux based terminal software.
For this sprint, I decided to use a principle of cucumber development which is the `.feature` file along with flowcharts, just to examine which approach is more effective for displaying algorithms.

I've read the documentations of the gherkin file, but I can't completely know if I formatted and wrote it in the way it's supposed to be, as there aren't many forums for discussing this matter:

```
# language: en


Feature: Signing panel
 
 A program with only a sign-up feature would not be able
 to provide multifarious interaction with its users
 in a expected exceptional manner. 
 Although, the idea of having a signing panel
 would not only indiciate this problem, but
 also provide a great methodology for implementing
 the sign-in feature.

 
 Scenario: The app is launched
  Given The user launches the app
    And The loading operation has succeeded
    And the user is greeted by the app

   Then Show the signing panel

  But if by any mean, the application have been interrupted
   Then safely close the app interface and clean the terminal


 Scenario: the sign-in option is decided
  Given the login panel is shown
   When the user chose the sign-in option
    Then Take the user app username

   When the username is validation checked
    And the username is found valid
    And the username exists in the database
     Then Take the users masterpassword
    
    But if by any mean, the username was not found valid
     Then inform the user
     And return to the base signing panel

   Given the masterpassword is validation checked
    And the masterpassword is found valid
    And the inserted masterpassword is the one that is alligned to the username
     Then log in
     And take the user to the main menu
   
    But if by any mean, the masterpassword was not found valid
     Then Inform the user
     And return to the base signing panel
```

Comment: Is it meaningful to review this single file, without the associated implementations of the tests?

Comment: @TobySpeight Greetings, unfortunately I'm not entirely familiar with the concepts of BDD, I'm adapting the gherkin file only for displaying the project algorithms and design patterns.

Comment: I've never worked with it either - I hope someone more knowledgeable can help us here!